# What's wrong with this MySql connect string

Tags: mysql

`Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=192.168.1.103;Database=mysql;User=root; Password=;Option=3;`

It works just fine when use localhost or 127.0.0.1, but not 198.168.1.100 (IP of the current machine).

---

MySql is part of Xampp on a Windwos machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on if MySQL is binding to `198.168.1.103` or not.

Edit:

To check how MySQL is listening, run the `netstat` command in a command promprt:

```
netstat -an | find "3306"
```

If it is listening on `192.168.1.103`, you should see an entry with that IP in the results. If you don't, then you will need to use `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` for your connections, unless you want to set it up otherwise.

---

Reply from OP: I get this

C:\Users\me>netstat -an | find "3306"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3306           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:3306         127.0.0.1:49973        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49973        127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED

C:\Users\me>

---

So you are indeed listening on all interfaces and `192.168.1.103` would be accessible. Looking over your login credentials, yes that would be the issue. You're trying to login as `root`, which will only have `localhost` network access.

Basically, when you're dealing with MySQL user permissions, you generally have a username, password, and hostname. With this in mind, the same user could require a different password to login, depending on where they are connecting from.

There is a way to make it so that root can connect through `192.168.1.103` but you **should not do this!** The reason is that the root user has complete access to your database. If you want to login still, you would need to create a new user, and set them as able to connect from  whatever IP address the MySQL server sees the user as, in the case `192.168.1.103`.

Comment: @Mawg What operating system is the MySQL server running?

Comment: MySql is part of Xampp on a Windwos machine. COuld you please have a look at this and tell me if that's my problem? I would guess so, but haven't tried it yet ...   http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=26963

Comment: @Mawg Please check my inline comments on how to see if MySQL is listening on `192.168.1.100`

Comment: I updated your question, because it was easier to get the layout right that way. BUT, what's about that link I posted "enabling remote access to MySql"?

Comment: @Mawg Yes the host access would be the issue, since you're already binding on all interfaces. Please see the more detailed inline response for more information.

Comment: @Mawg A word of advice, you should search around a bit for articles and documentation on MySQL permissions. It's critical from a security perspective that you understand how they work, even if this is just a throw away server to learn how it works.